# Extract values at point locations from an xarray DataArray, and get all other values separately

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have an xarray DataArray as follows:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

da = xr.DataArray(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), dims=['x', 'y'], coords={'x': np.arange(5), 'y': np.arange(5)})
```

It looks like this:

[image: DataArray]

I want to select the values of the data array that are closest to some specific x, y point locations that I have.

To do this, I can put those point co-ordinates into DataArrays themselves, and index using those:

```
x_coords = xr.DataArray([1.2, 3.6, 4.9])
y_coords = xr.DataArray([2.2, 0.7, 4.3])

da.sel(x=x_coords, y=y_coords, method='nearest')
```

This gives the expected result of `[7, 21, 24]`.

However, I now want to get the 'other' elements of the array. That is, the ones that are in cells that *aren't* the nearest cells to the point locations I gave. In this case, this would be all the numbers from 0 to 24 *excluding* 7, 21 and 24. However, in my real array the values are not unique like this.

How can I get these values?

I wondered if I could do something using sets, but I would need to treat the x and y co-ordinates together, as the co-ordinates come in pairs, and I couldn't work out how to do this.

If necessary, I'm happy with a numpy-only solution, but I'd prefer a pure xarray solution.

Comment: The arrays are two-dimensional - what exactly do you want to happen to the missing values? Are you just hoping to NaN them? As you suggest, you can't just drop a single (x, y) point from the middle of the array.

Comment: I was actually aiming not to have to modify the array at all, and just extract the values at all the other locations. I guess I could just set the values at the selected locations to NaN and that would filter them out. I think it'd be cleaner to be able to extract them without modifying the array though.